# Spring Boot logback-spring.xml creates a log file under path /var/log even if custom log path is defined in the xml and application.properties files

Tags: spring-boot, rollingfileappender, application.properties, spring-logback

I prepared a custom `RollingFileAppender` configuration in the `logback-spring.xml` file and `application.properties` files. The log file soduncu.log created under path `/var/app/sefa/logs`. This is expected behavior for the configuration but there is an unexpected situation that `soduncu.log` created under default Linux log path `/var/log/`. I tried to prevent this unexpected log file creation but I couldn't. What is the situation here and what I did wrong?

logback-spring.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<springProperty name="LOG_DIR" source="logging.path" defaultValue="/var/app/sefa/logs">
</springProperty>
<appender name="ROLLING"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_DIR}/soduncu.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/soduncu-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
        </fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
        <totalSizeCap>20GB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<root level="WARN">
    <appender-ref ref="ROLLING" />
</root> 
</configuration>
```

application.properties:

```
logging.path=/var/app/sefa/logs
logging.file=/var/app/sefa/logs/soduncu.log
logging.level.root=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework=ERROR
logging.level.com.nuvia=DEBUG
```

Here is the one Linux process id link to a log file under two different path:

```
/proc/14368/fd/1 -> /var/log/soduncu.log
/proc/14368/fd/2 -> /var/log/soduncu.log
/proc/14368/fd/6 -> /var/app/sefa/logs/soduncu.log
```

Comment: logging.file should be just the file name without the path,

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I already covered this file in the ```<file>${LOG_DIR}/soduncu.log</file>```. It has not used anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to replicate this behavior with your code. 
Try to change

```
name="LOG_DIR" source="logging.path"
```

to

```
name="LOG_DIR_PATH" source="log.dir.path"
```

and see what happens
**make sure to delete soduncu.log from var/log first.**
I hope it helps.